# Does networkmanager supports LEAP/WPA2/AES?

Tags: networkmanager

I know I will have to connect through wireless that is using WPA2/LEAP/AES.

Will my networkmanager connect to this network?

UPDATE: then why can't I find "AES" or CCMP in my nm-applet on Ubuntu 10.04?

Comment: It surely supports WPA2-CCMP-AES. I'm pretty sure it does LEAP as well.

Comment: Yes it does....

Answer (score 1):

According to the announcements for Fedora 13 (2010) NetworkManager suports WPA personal and enterprise.

Answer (score 0):

Wireless connections are handled through WPA Supplicant; [which supports WPA2, LEAP, AES, and more](http://hostap.epitest.fi/wpa_supplicant/).

Comment: NetworkManager does not handle all the type of connections that wpa_supplicant supports, so this is not sufficient.